# What does "Hold cross" mean?

Tags: meaning

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury), Judge Harkin says this below lines at the end of court session:

> Judge: We'll adjourn. **Hold cross** till tomorrow. Release the jury 45
> minutes early.

What does "Hold cross" mean?

Comment: I haven't seen the film, but since this appears to be a courtroom drama they're presumably talking about "cross-examination" which they will hold until tomorrow?

Comment: You are asking me a question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman that could be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Cross" is an abbreviation for "cross-examination".

The judge is saying that the process of cross-examination will be held until the next day in court.